# Split text field in two part ; in yii

Tags: yii, textfield

[image: Text field]

As you can see the remarks text field is out of the form; i want to split it into two and put the second part down under the first one.

How to do that?

Comment: if so , then use textarea

Comment: thnx; it's a substitute but i think it will do for now

Answer (score 1):

set some style to limit its width in **htmlOptions**

```
echo $form->textField($model, 'remarks', array(
  'class' => 'span3', // set class for it
  //'style' => 'width: 200px;', // or set style to limit the width
));
```

**htmlOptions** is also usable in `CHtml`

Comment: i don't want to limit the width, i just want to break it into two.

Comment: then you have to echo two seperate text fields and handle them in your controller

Answer (score 1):

Try to use textarea field against input

```
echo $form->textArea($model, 'remarks');
```